# Redirect ex.com/en/* to ex.com/* using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've just moved my website from sub-directory to root , But the search engines still have the old urls listed in there Index. Till the time fresh URL's get listed.

Is there any way to redirect those requests to that main domain.
**Old URL: example.com/en/testurl
New URL: example.com/testurl**
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my site under subfolder and I decided to move to the root level of the domain.

The main challenge was to keep all articles on the same path as a subfolder.

Guess what it’s possible through RewriteCond in Apache web server.

This is possible through “.htaccess”

Ensure to take a backup of an existing file (.htaccess)
Add the below line and save the file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Remember to replace "subfolder" with your previous installation directory.

In the last line, I used 3 flags.

1. **R=301** (permanent redirect)
2. **NC** (Case insensitive)
3. **L** (last - stop processing rules)

This worked for me and I hope for you too.